# Allow entire controller in CakePHP Auth and allow() doesn't work

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have tried to perform

`$this->Auth->allow()` in `beforeFilter()` but, I need to add entire controller as an exception, i.e. it needs to be public and does not require user to be signed in.

Just a short-cut way to perform `$this->Auth->allow( every-function-in-this-controller )`

Answers?

**Edit:**

I have this:

```
<?php

App::uses('AppController','Controller');

class AllzonesController extends AppController {

    public function __beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('index');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->layout = 'main';
        $this->set('Hello',"Hello world");
    }
}
```

It is transferring Auth-login()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you proposed is the appropiate way of what you want to do

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow();
}
```

Reading the [API docs](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-AuthComponent.html#_allow)

> Takes a list of actions in the current controller for which authentication is not required, or no parameters to allow all actions.

So the function with no parameters should allow a normal user (not logged in) to access every action of that controller.

**EDIT :**

Sorry, missed the version reference in your tag. [In here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public) it says

```
 $this->Auth->allow('*');
```

is the appropiate way for Cake 2.0 (and previous versions, as noted by @mark)

Comment: We are on same lines mate : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-1-migration-guide.html#authcomponent Yes, it has been deprecated (removed). I am using 2.3.5

Comment: Then you should put the appropiate version tag :) Anyway, if you use `allow()`, it does not give you what you want?

Comment: "is the appropiate way for Cake 2.0" => ... and before, of course :)

Answer (score 3):

For versions beyond CakePHP 2.1

`$this->Auth->allow()`
instead of `$this->Auth->allow('*')`

and

To my other question `__beforeFiter` is not a magic function!

```
<?php

App::uses('AppController','Controller');

class AllzonesController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('index');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->layout = 'main';
        $this->set('Hello',"Hello world");
    }
}
```